# Simple outlier detection for time series

Tags: python, anomaly-detection

I wanted to generate a very simple example of anomaly detection for time series. So I created sample data with one very obvious outlier. Here's a picture of the data:

[image]

The problem is, I didn't get any method to detect the outlier reliably so far. I tried local outlier factor, isolation forests, k nearest neighbors and DBSCAN. From what I read, at least one of those methods should be suitable. I also tried tweaking the parameters but that didn't really help.

What mistake do I make here? Are the methods not appropriate?

Below is a code example.

Thanks in advance!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)

t=np.linspace(0,10,101).reshape(-1,1)
y_test=0.5+t+t**2+2*np.random.randn(len(t),1)

y_test[10]=y_test[10]*7

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,y_test)
plt.show;

from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor

clf=LocalOutlierFactor(contamination=0.1)
pred=clf.fit_predict(y_test)

plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(t[pred==1],y_test[pred==1],'bx')
plt.plot(t[pred==-1],y_test[pred==-1],'ro')
plt.show

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

clf=IsolationForest(behaviour='new',contamination='auto')
pred=clf.fit_predict(y_test)

plt.figure(4)
plt.plot(t[pred==1],y_test[pred==1],'bx')
plt.plot(t[pred==-1],y_test[pred==-1],'ro')
plt.show

from pyod.models.knn import KNN

clf = KNN()
clf.fit(y_test)
pred=clf.predict(y_test)

plt.figure(5)
plt.plot(t[pred==0],y_test[pred==0],'bx')
plt.plot(t[pred==1],y_test[pred==1],'ro')
plt.show

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

clf = DBSCAN(min_samples=10,eps=3)
pred=clf.fit_predict(y_test)

plt.figure(5)
plt.plot(t[pred==0],y_test[pred==0],'bx')
plt.plot(t[pred==1],y_test[pred==1],'ro')
plt.show
```

Comment: If you are dealing with timeseries I suggest you TSMOOTHIE: A python library for timeseries smoothing and outlier detection in a vectorized way https://github.com/cerlymarco/tsmoothie

Comment: @MarcoCerliani examples in this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/593074/32249 use `tsmoothie`, yet the question is rather on statistics and not on the use of the package itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this type of outlier a filter should work. For instance, a moving average is a filter, and can be applied here in a trend/noise decomposition framework:
$$T_i=\frac 1 n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_{i-k}
\\N_i=x_i-T_i$$

When the noise component is "too large" it indicates an outlier.

Here's a Python implementation:

```
for i in np.arange(len(T)):
    T[i] = np.mean(y_test[np.max([0,i-m]):(i+1)])

plt.plot(t, T)
N = y_test[:,0] - T
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,N)
plt.show()

np.std(N)
```

The plot of your series with a trend:
[image]

The plot of the noise:
[image]

As you can see the noise component jumps at the outlier to 30 while the standard deviation of a noise is ~4. You can also calculate the moving window dispersion of the noise, and detect an outlier when the noise sticks out of the running volatility.

This filter is very similar to an outlier test known as [Grubbs](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h1.htm). Here, I'm using the moving window as a sample in Grubbs test.

Comment: Thanks, this looks quite good. I just don't get it to work in python, since the variables T and m are not defined in your code snippet.

Comment: The "problem" with this method is, that it requires me to specify a model for the data first and then look at the deviation from that model. I could have also fit a polynomial to the data instead of the moving average, but I wondered if there is a simpler solution to the problem using some of the algorithms that I proposed. I still don't really understand why they do not work with time trend. Without the time influence, they work quite fine actually.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate parametric method is called Intervention Detection http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html where you include/account for possible ARIMA process in the identification of the latent deterministic structure (  1 pulse in your example )

I don't know if this procedure is available in python.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't read that paper so far. As far as I can tell, this ARIMA model is a little bit more advanced, but similar to the moving average model, as proposed in the answer by Aksakal. I think this works fine for the purpose.

Comment: An arima model is an optimized "moving average" where the optimal "n" and the optimal weights are used to create the error process while validating that the variance of the errors is homogeneous through time. Deterministic structure other than "pulses" can also be found e.g. a level/step shift.  The approach of Aksakal is quick and a little too dirty for me BUT will work under some circumstances.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive–moving-average_model gives us the relationship between arima and weighted averages in presenting an autoregressive process of order p. Note that all arima process can be represented as pure ar processes thus then a weighted average of the past.

Comment: Y(t )= k + ph1*Y(t-1) + phi2*Y(t-2) ... + phip*Y(t-p) + e(t)

Answer (score 0):

The outlier has an OK absolute value (on the right hand side there are normal values just as high), it is only anomalous because it deviates significantly from the time steps around it. When only passing in single samples to the anomaly detector this is impossible to learn, instead have to use some time window.
This can be as simple as using the previous N samples as features for each timestep. So called lagged features. Windows size is a hyperparameter, 2-10 should work OK in this case. Since the difference might be informative one can also compute and pass in those. Probably Isolation Forest will catch the anomaly in this case.
An autoencoder with a small LSTM or GRU is probably a better option though, again using a small time window.